# Create NSManagedObject class in Xcode 8.1 showing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've created `NSManagedObject` class for entity in Xcode 8 using edition->create `NSManagedObject` subclass.  It creates 2files one with `+CoreDataProperties` extension and another with `+CoreDataClass` extension.

After adding these files am getting error **Linker command failed** and its showing duplicate files... I have checked whether the file is added two times on finder as well as in Xcode

If I remove `CoreDataClass.m` file from compile sources that error has gone but the app is crashing. I can't able to access the properties of entity class.  How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a NSManagedObject make sure your **Codegen** is `Manual/None`.

Select your **Entity**, on the Data Model Inspector (right hand side) under **Class**, change your **Codegen** to `Manual/None` then Create your `NSManagedObject`.

If you have already created you `NSManagedObject` and the duplicate files error has already shown, delete your Derived Data (File -> Workspace Settings -> Click your derived data folder link), Clean Build Folder (Redundant? Not sure), and create your `NSManagedObject` as shown above.

Comment: Changing Codegen to Manual/None solves my issue but what is the need of that

Comment: Thanks , making Codegen to Manual/None worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because post Xcode 8.0 now it create class file for your core data entity by it's own. You can add extension (for this class) if you want to write some addition functionality.

SO just remove the classes clean project, (may be relaunch Xcode if problem persist) and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.2

by convention , and more common approach , you should generate category/extensions  in codegen in entity inspecter , then you manually create a subclass of NSManagedObject (again more common to name the class with the same name as the Entity) and you're good to go ,
 the reason why you need to have a class/extension of your Entities is that it's much easier to deal with your entity attributes as vars , not "manually" like using value(forKey: " ")as Any?, 
because when it comes to saving dates with this technique even if you "as" it to a Date or String , 
Swift is a bit "allergic" to type Any , because it's not strongly referred , that's why we avoid using Any as much as possible